# Cross compile for ARM without installing anything

Tags: compiling, cross-compilation

I have to cross compile bluez for another machine, but i am not allowed to install anything on the host machine. I never did this before. How can i get started?

**Host machine:**

```
Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2420 0 @ 1.90GHz
OS Version: Linux 2.6.32-44 generic
```

**Target machine:**

```
Processor: ARM926EJ-S rev 5 (v5l)
OS Version: Linux 2.6.35.3-571
```

As you can see the Target Machine has a newer version of Linux then the host machine, is it even possible to cross compile in this situation?
I found [this site](http://www.linux-magazin.de/Ausgaben/2008/04/GNU-Tools-mal-kreuzweise) (german), is this a good tutorial on how to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel version has no bearing on compiling code for another system.

Unfortunately without being able to install *any* software on the host system you're going to be out of luck. You need a compiler suite that will generate code for your target platform (ARM in this case) and by default such a compiler suite isn't installed on most systems - if they have a compiler installed, it'll be for the same architecture.

That said, if you can install software in your home directory on the host, you can install a cross compiler. There are any number of guides online (for example, [this one](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler)). Basically, it involves downloading the source code for a compiler suite and compiling it on your host system so that it can generate binaries for your target architecture.

That said - why do you need to compile BlueZ from source? I don't know what distribution your ARM system is running, but Debian has [ARM packages](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/bluez) available (although the packages for *squeeze* are probably more appropriate based on the vintage of your ARM kernel).

Comment: Installing such tools in the user's home is a bad idea, unless you know exactly what you are doing (and then OP wouldn't be asking). Use the tools your distribution provides.

Comment: @vonbrand There's no guarantee that the distribution provides an ARM cross compiler in its standard repositories (eg, finding one in EPEL for Red Hat based distributions can be difficult). Compiling a cross-compiler from source is often required... But yes, both building the compiler (if required) and cross-compiling require a certain level of skill.

Comment: I need to compile BlueZ from source because i am not allowed to update, upgrade or install anything on the host machine. But compiling is not a problem, i already found out how to do this. Only cross-compiling is a problem, because i never did it before.